# Read Properties in Jenkins Pipeline and Pass Variable to Powershell

Tags: powershell, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins Pipeline script which is intended to do the following steps

1. Read a property file from another job in Jenkins
2. Extract the variable from the Property file
3. Use the variable and update a POM file using Powershell, so that other steps can be executed

Reading of the file and echoing the variable is working fine, but the variable passed from the property file is not recognized by PowerShell script somehow as xml file node is remaining empty

Below is the Pipeline script

```
pipeline  {

    agent { 

        label { 
    label'Test'
        customWorkspace "C:\\workspace"
    }
    }

 stages {

stage('Checkout code') {
  steps {
    script {
     checkout .......

    }

  }
}

stage ('Pre Steps') {

 steps {

     script {


        copyRemoteArtifacts '........'
    properties = readProperties file :'test.properties

    echo "${properties.test_version}"

    powershell label: '', script: '''$pomPath = Resolve-Path .\\pom.xml

$xml = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument 

$xml.PreserveWhitespace = $true

$xml.Load($pomPath)

$xml.project.properties."testapplciation.version" ="${properties.test_version}"

$xml.Save($pomPath)'''
```

Please, can someone help, what could be wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to work it out by doing the following

```
def properties = readProperties file :'test.properties'
env['test_version'] =properties['test_version']
```

use the environment variable in PowerShell like this

```
$xml.project.properties."testapplciation.version" ="$Env:test_version"
```

This approach would require script approvals but it seems to be working for me.